# Como importar um repositório Git para Azure Repos?

Tags: microsoft-azure

O Azure Repos é um serviço do Azure DevOps. É possível importar um repositório Git de outro serviço de storage de Git para ele?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom dia,

É possível Importar o repositório. Na opção de Repositório tem a opção de Import repository

[image: Opção]

Apos ir nessa importação abrirá uma outra tela a qual poderá informar o link de clone do projeto e as credenciais:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]